# Justification for CLS specification : The accessibility of the property and of its accessors must be identical

Tags: .net, cls-compliant

Was just running through the ruleset of Parasoft's code analysis tool.

```
public int testProperty // violation
{
  private get // not matching property accessibility
  { return _testValue; }
  set
  { _testValue = value; }
}
```

The fix to make them both match. The reason points to the properties section on [this MSDN Page on the CLS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12a7a7h3%28vs.71%29.aspx). However the justification for this is not mentioned on the page.

I frequently use automatic properties of the form 
`public int MyProp { get; private set;}`

Is this a violation of the CLS ? RFC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at a [more recent version of that page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12a7a7h3%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) (or even the [.NET 2.0 version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12a7a7h3%28v=VS.80%29.aspx)) it doesn't have that rule. Basically it went away between v1.1 and v2.0... at the same time when C# started allowing them to be specified differently :)

It was a silly rule, and a silly lack-of-feature in C# 1, IMO. It's *obviously* useful to be able to have a private setter and a public getter. It's pretty rare to have it the other way round, admittedly...

Comment: Doh! MSDN needs a more prominent way of showing that the page is outdated. I just clicked the link provided in the description of the parasoft rule. Thanks Jon. This means I need to check every parasoft SCA rule now :(

Comment: The version *is* the first thing beneath the title :) Can you specify which version the Parasoft tool targets?

Comment: yeah I was thinking more of a gray/disabled background color or a huge OUT-OF-DATE watermark :) Nope, there isn't a target framework setting. There are just a set of around 400 rules - I've just spent a couple of days with it, I wouldn't shell out my money for this. Half of the rules are pretty flaky. More details on my blog in case anyone's interested.